# hardware clock settings

Tags: linux

how can i read and write hardware clock (system clock) using c program on linux...thnxxx

Answer (score 1):

Study `hwclock` sources. Also have a look at section `How hwclock Accesses the Hardware Clock` in `man 8 hwclock`.